# error TS2339: Property 'sendemailverification' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'

Tags: typescript, angular-cli-v6

I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'sendemailverification' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'
```

it's my code 
i using firebase email verification

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
const fullname = form.value.fullname;
const email = form.value.email;
const password = form.value.password;

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(userData => {
    //error
    userData.sendemailverification();
    console.log(userData);
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is `sendEmailVerification` not `sendemailverification`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `userData.user.sendEmailVerification()` to make it work.